# How to check whether there is difference in two array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There is a similar question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript) in this question we need to get the difference in the array.

But I just want true or false. I don't need the different array.

I tried it like this:

`groups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}]`

`checkedgroups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}, {id: 3, name: "check 3"}]`

My solution:
`_.differenceBy(groups, checkedGroups, 'id').length`

Comment: What is your `differenceBy` function?

Comment: Please post your `differenceBy` function. I suspect the error is caused by something in there.

Comment: If you need length difference then why no `checkedgroups.length - groups.length`

Comment: @brk i need to check the difference by considering  id as common between these two aray.

Comment: @vikas95prasad There is no built-in `differenceBy` function in JavaScript.

Comment: Okay, then how can I use lodash ```differenceBy``` function?

Comment: You say you want a `true` or `false` as your output, but then at the bottom of your question, you say you expect a number representing the length as the output? Which one is it?

Comment: Okay I will edit the question wait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can try different arrays and check the output. It uses a filter function. If the elements are not equal the array returned by filter is empty. Otherwise array of length of the original array is returned.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b'];
var b = ['a', 'b'];

function w(a, b) {
  if (a.length != b.length)
    return false;
  else {
    var k = a.filter((e) => b[a.indexOf(e)] == e)
    if (k.length == 0)
      return false;
    else if (k.length == a.length)
      return true
  }
}
console.log(w(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arrays of id's to compare the string version of the arrays:

```js
var groups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}]

var checkedgroups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}, {id: 3, name: "check 3"}]

function differenceBy(g, c, id){
  var id1 = JSON.stringify(g.map(i => i[id]));
  var id2 = JSON.stringify(c.map(i => i[id]));
  if(id1 == id2) return true;
  else return false;
}


console.log(differenceBy(groups, checkedgroups, 'id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isEqualWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqualWith) as follows:

```
_.isEqualWith(array, other, (objValue, othValue) => {
  if(objValue.id === otherValue.id && objValue.name === otherValue.name){
   return true'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a JSON string

```
try{
    return JSON.stringify(groups) === JSON.stringify(checkedgroups);
} catch(e) {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of items which differ from one array to another you can map both your objects to an array of `id`'s (or whatever you set the `prop` argument to). You can then use `.filter` to get the difference of `arr1 - arr2`. Lastly, you can then return the `.length` of the difference between the two arrays.

See working example below:

```js
const groups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}],
checkedgroups = [{id: 1, name: "check 1"}, {id: 2, name: "check 2"}, {id: 3, name: "check 3"}];

const differenceBy = (arr1, arr2, prop) => {
  const arrProp1 = arr1.map((obj) => obj[prop]),
  arrProp2 = arr2.map((obj) => obj[prop]),
  
  dif = arrProp1.filter(num => !arrProp2.includes(num));
  return dif.length;
}

console.log(differenceBy(checkedgroups, groups, "id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare any objects with each other (**which have no circular reference**) use these:
If you're sure whether they ain't null and undefined:
`JSON.stringify(groups) === JSON.stringify(checkedgroups)`

Otherwise:
`JSON.stringify(groups || null) === JSON.stringify(checkedgroups || null)`